# OpsWorks nginx namespace conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-solo, opsworks

I want to deploy one of my cookbooks, nginx-passenger, to opsworks. I've tested the cookbooks locally already using testkitchen and all the recipes and tests passed successfully. However, when using opsworks, the run of nginx-passenger::default fails with the error "Could not satisfy version constraints for: nginx". Opsworks has already a cookbook with exactly the same name, but a different version, so it's probably caused by that.

I searched for this error already and just found the following https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=153656

However this doesn't offer a real solution.

My files look like the following:

my_cookbooks/Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.getchef.com"

cookbook 'user', '~> 0.3.0'
cookbook 'apt', '~> 2.6.0'
cookbook 'nginx', '~> 2.7.4'
```

my_cookbooks/nginx-passenger/metadata.rb

```
name "nginx-passenger"
version "0.1.0"

depends 'nginx', '~> 2.7.4'
depends 'apt', '~> 2.6.0'
```

Can you recommend a workaround this problem. I really want to use the community nginx cookbook here.

EDIT: Pardon, I forgot to mention few details. I'm trying to create a custom layer, but I didn't assign any recipes to it yet. I've created an instance, updated custom cookbooks and executed the recipe nginx-passenger::default manually.

Answer (score 1):

Naming conflicts are a known problem with the OpsWorks cookbooks and there isn't an easy solution.

What you might have to do is download both community nginx and nginx-passenger cookbooks to your cookbook directory, rename the nginx cookbook to something like nginx-community then update any references in the nginx-passenger cookbook from nginx to nginx-community.

On the other hand, you should probably consider whether you really need the nginx and nginx-passenger community cookbooks. OpsWorks has its own cookbooks for nginx and passenger, it's just that the default ruby stack uses Apache. You'd probably only need to overwrite a file or two in the nginx cookbook to make it work with passenger though.